# What are the differences between "amalgam" and "hodgepodge"/"hedgepodge"?

Tags: meaning, differences

What are the differences between *amalgam* and *hodgepodge/hedgepodge*? I see people using them in their sentences, which seems to mean mixture of many things. Are they subtly different?

Comment: I never heard "hedgepodge" used.  Is that a mixed-up hedgehog? :-p

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. When asking a question on the difference between words it is customary, here, that you first look up the words in a dictionary (e.g. [Oxford Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/)) and then explain why the definitions leave you confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the are different. It's a matter of the amount of randomness.  An amalgam is a mixture of certain proportions.  A commonly used material with which a dentist fills a tooth is called an amalgam.  It starts out soft and hardens into a semi-permanent filling.  It is a mixture--an alloy-- that consists chiefly of silver mixed with mercury and variable amounts of other metals.

Human personalities are often referred to as amalgams of various types.  For example, the pre-scientific labels for temperaments (melancholy, sanguine, choleric, and phlegmatic), though flawed, still have some applicability to human personalities, with each person embodying an amalgam of two--sometimes more--of those four temperaments, but in certain proportions.  I, for example, am strongly melancholic, but I also am a bit phlegmatic.

A hodgepodge, on the other hand, is also a mixture, but the mixture is random and all jumbled together.  That's the method I use to make a one-frying-pan meal.  I take whatever happens to be available in my kitchen, throw it all together in the pan, and cook it.  Sometimes it tastes pretty darn good; other times, not so much.  With food, a hodgepodge dish is called a mélange.

Comment: +1 Or, less extravagantly, a *hash*; or, even more extravagantly, a *gallimaufry*.

Comment: But the mediaeval theory maintained that all four humors are present and that health depended upon their equal temperament.

Comment: The impression I got from researching this is that the difference is not so much about the randomness of the ingredients, but the randomness of the resulting mixture. Amalgams are well-integrated, but hodgepodges are still pretty random.

Comment: @StonyB:  You're probably right.  I was influenced by a 20th century writer who used the four "bodily humours" as a springboard for a discussion of human temperament.  His theory, controversial though it may be, is that most people have a dominant "humour."  When the dominant trait and an admixture of the other three combine in unique ways, certain patterns of behavior tend to emerge, along with concomitant strengths and weaknesses.  Once we discover and accept our "hard wiring," we are better able to be ourselves and at the same time hone our rough edges, which we all have.

Comment: @BraddSzonye:  Perhaps my use of the word "randomness" was ill advised.  "Serendipitous" might work, although that word has a positive connotation, whereas the word "hodgepodge" does not.  A hodgepodge, though, could comprise a felicitous mixture.  As I said in my answer, my one-frying-pan meals do on occasion taste pretty good!  I guess you could say I get lucky sometimes when, for example, two or more of my ingredients' flavors marry in a serendipitous way.  Now if only I could duplicate that recipe the next time . . ..

Answer (score 3):

[*Amalgam*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amalgam) is literally an alloy containing mercury, such as the [kind used in dentistry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amalgam_%28dentistry%29). As a synonym for [*mixture,*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mix) it implies homogeneity. [*Amalgamation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amalgamation) is a process of combining disparate things into a unified whole, like a corporate merger.

In contrast, a [*hodgepodge*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hodgepodge) is a jumble of miscellaneous things. It lacks the implications of homogeneity and integration. The example from Wiktionary:

> His latest sculpture is a hodgepodge of kitchen clutter and scrap glued together. In fact, all his recent pieces have been similar hodgepodges.

Comment: Did you mean to type alloy? :-)